# Launchpad has a different style to the views

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

i have a question.

Why is the style of the view a different one in the launchpad as without ?
Its kinda annoying because some of the labels or inputs sometimes gets readjust and than it is not clean. The ui looks way smaller, can it be fixed? I tryed already to put `"fullWidth": true` in the manifest but yeah no changes.. when i open the dev menu and delete the `sapUiSizeCompact` from the body in the launchpad then it looks normal. But i did never set the `sapUiSizeCompact` is there a way to remove it?

Example:
Not launchpad
[image: Not launchpad]

In the Launchpad
[image: In the Launchpad]

Comment: Adjusting the density depends on the application. Typically the application's `Component.js` would implement `getContentDensityClass` something like this: https://github.com/SAP/openui5-worklist-app/blob/79bea14cc36c312343ec29f6a990d8c573abe31e/webapp/Component.js#L47-L66

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann mhm.. so i have to set it to every element? or i missunderstand something. If i search for the method, the ```sapUiSizeCozy```and ```sapUiSizeCompact``` just set as styleclasses..

Answer (score 0):

i found a way but it seems you have to set it per user.. i am not really happy but maybe someone know how to do it as a standard so the user dont have to set it by deafult. You can set this option in the settings of the flp

[image]